# Not able to insert button in the linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, button, android-linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#AFEEEE"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="ORDERS"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary">

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

Whenever I try to put a button below the ViewPager, it sinks down below the screen. While resizing it, it only changes it's size below the screen. I want to put it below the viewPager.

Comment: @MittalVarsani Changed, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your viewpager height 0dp and layout_weight=1, It will work

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager       
android:id="@+id/pager"   
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="1"
> 
</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

Comment: It worked ! I'm gonna accept this as the answer. What's the reason behind that?

Comment: so there is a property weight in linearlayout, when all the sibling views are of fixed height/wrap_content they take their space, and the view which you are goving weight=1, they cover the remaining all the space, u can google about weight property for further info